# Formatting CSOM output

Tags: client-object-model

I have a list and using CSOM to surface information. However all the examples I found show an alert box or Gridview to output the information.

I would like the list items to show in a tabular form, this could be div or something so I can style it. In addition it would be useful to have some sort of pagination, i.e. a link to show next set of list items (in batches).

The following code  pages through a list but gives an alert box, need to modify it so it shows in tabular form.

Any ideas?

```
    var listItems;                   //holds retrieved list items 
var query;                       //must continue to reuse the same query object for paging to work 
var targetList;                  //list from which to retrieve items 
var ctx; 

function runCode() { 
    ctx = new SP.ClientContext(); 
    targetList = ctx.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Test1'); 
    query = new SP.CamlQuery(); 
    query.set_viewXml("<View><ViewFields><FieldRef Name='Title'/></ViewFields><RowLimit>2</RowLimit></View>"); 
    listItems = targetList.getItems(query); 
    ctx.load(listItems);  
    ctx.executeQueryAsync(onQuerySucceeded, onQueryFailed); 
} 

function onQuerySucceeded() { 
    var message = "Found Matching Items! "; 
    var listEnumerator = listItems.getEnumerator(); 
    while (listEnumerator.moveNext())  { 
    message += "nTitle=" + listEnumerator.get_current().get_item("Title") 
    } 
    alert(message); 
    var position = listItems.get_listItemCollectionPosition(); 
    if (position != null) { 
    query.set_listItemCollectionPosition(position); 
    listItems = targetList.getItems(query); 
    ctx.load(listItems);   
    ctx.executeQueryAsync(onQuerySucceeded, this.onQueryFailed); 
    } 
} 

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) { 
    alert('Request failed. nError: ' + args.get_message() + 'nStackTrace: ' + args.get_stackTrace()); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting an alert window because the code has an alert statement. You can remove below code to fix that

```
alert(message);
```

To answer you question about Sorting, Filtering, Pagination etc. You can use Out of the box list view for that. Otherwise if you want to custom coding will take lot of time and effort.

In 2013 there is a new concept called JSLinks which can be used to modify the look and feel of a list view. You should start thinking in that perspective to easily achieve your requirements.

Comment: I would like to custom code the output and not use the ootb list view. Any pointers on how to achieve some sort of tabular layout using custom code?

Comment: You mean Serverside object model? You can use `SPGridView` control for displaying in tabular form. It supports Paging/Sorting (For enabling it require a bit of coding).

Comment: is SPGridView available through CSOM?

Comment: Which CSOM Library you are using .Net or JavaScript?

Comment: I dont have access to the server box so I guess its Javascript?

Comment: Then you can use any of the jQuery plugins.http://www.sitepoint.com/30-amazing-jquery-tables/

Comment: Can I access .net through CSOM also?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18555/discussion-between-user32056-and-amal-hashim).